# HTML Email: Text size increase Google Inbox

Tags: android, html-email, google-inbox

When coding emails, and testing in Litmus, I am noticing Google Inbox for Android makes the text larger than actual size, which causes issues in layout especially on buttons.
I have tried all kinds of solutions, even the ones on this page: http://freshinbox.com/blog/targeting-new-gmail-css/  with no luck. Has anyone out there come across a fi for this?

Comment: if you paste some code for the offending area of the HTML then someone can have a look at it. Personally i havent had any issues with Inbox.

Comment: its not a particular area, ALL text are getting enlarged on every email. I'd like to believe its a recent thing. If you look at the link above there used to be a fix but due to recent updates (Sept 18) those fixes do not work anymore.

Comment: Gmail have recently rolled out media query support, tried using media query to fix it? You can target only Inbox if needed. Make sure your media queries are coded right or it gets stripped.

Comment: @Syfer yes media queries are now supported, Inbox seems to allow most css yet all text is enlarged. Not sure how to target Inbox only, please post any hacks/rules that you know.

Comment: The hack is on that link from your original post. Use that in the media query and see if it works

Comment: As I posted above I tried everything on that page already and it does not work for me. My coworker, different team, also tried the tips on that page for his emails and had with no luck.

Comment: I just tested an email I had created a few days ago and it's rendering as expected. Since you have not posted any code for the issues you are having I can't be of any help. When/if you do post your code then someone can help you out.

Comment: @syfer here's one email the I put into Codepen: https://codepen.io/roobz/pen/QqYEKY    
Direct link: [http://troncdev.com/email-halloween/template.php?market=la&version=1&type=acquisition]     
Heres another email: [http://troncdev.com/email-ra-good-health/template.php?market=bs&version=1&type=acquisition&submarket=]

Comment: Here is the Litmus test results altho im not sure if a login is required: https://litmus.com/checklist/emails/public/767003a

Comment: Just checked on Google inbox and this is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI7ZV.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEZmx.png. Apart from the start trial button everything else looks fine to me

Comment: That mighta been a bad example, text headline lockup is image, even then the button is messed up as you stated which is an issue. If you look at this email [http://troncdev.com/email-pandora/template.php?market=bs&version=1&type=acquisition&submarket=] the text enlarging is causing some undesirable text wrapping and messing up the button. As I mentioned this is not a code specific issue, we need a hack to stop the text zooming. Here's another eg, the header is completely getting messed up: [http://troncdev.com/email-trust-expertise/template.php?market=bs&version=4&type=acquisition&submarket=]

Comment: This issue is still unsolved. If anyone knows how to get dev tools working on an Android phone let me know. I can get Chrome to detect and see browser screens but it does not detect email screens from Inbox. That would let us see why Inbox is behaving this way with the text zooming.